# String or binary data would be truncated in SQL Server by user

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I get the error

> String or binary data would be truncated

when I run an insert statement with one user id, but not with another ID.

I wouldn't think that error would be user id specific but perhaps it can be?

Anyone know if that error message can be suppressed by user?

Comment: What is the datatype for the column? Show your insert statement

Comment: It depends on the length of columns used to store columns.  Without table definitions and sample inserts, it is hard to say much more.

Comment: Can you show more detail? The datatypes of each field you are trying to insert into would be helpful.

Comment: But could that at all be user specific where the insert statement is 100% the same?

Comment: Errr, no.  Perhaps you should give us a few more clues.. what structure is your table in, and (more importantly) what data are you trying to insert ?  This error is very-well documented, and just says you're trying to insert a string/blob which is too long for a database field.

Comment: Does the table you are inserting to have a trigger, or a "CreatedUser" column (or similar) with a default constraint of `SYSTEM_USER`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is specific to the data in the insert. If one user has a longer name than the field you are entering it into  for example and another doesn't, the first will error and the second will not.  This is why it is critical to understand your data when setting up tables. and it is critical to understand what information you are sending in a specific action query in order to troubleshoot it.

Comment: The insert statement is 100% the same. The username is not being inserted.

Comment: So the only thing different in the data is the id? Not any other field in the insert is different? That seems odd to me why woudl you want two users to have the same data?. Name was just an example, it could be any field, email, address, etc. Not having your actual insert and table structure, I can't say what field it is.

Comment: You are right. It was a "hidden" thing. Constraint was inserting the username to a field.

Comment: You have a table structure problem then and or an application problem. A user should not be able to create a user name longer than the field size of any tables it will be going into.

Answer (score 0):

may be the size of data u want to insert is  more than the size of the field limit u set. like u should set something(MAX)